# Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: python, mysql

I have a huge table and I need to process all rows in it. I'm always getting this Lost connection message and I'm not able to reconnect and restore the cursor to the last position it was. This is basically the code I have here:

```
#
import MySQLdb

class DB:
  conn = None

  def connect(self):
    self.conn = MySQLdb.connect('hostname', 'user', '*****', 'some_table', cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)

  def query(self, sql):
    try:
     cursor = self.conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute(sql)
   except (AttributeError, MySQLdb.OperationalError):
     self.connect()
     cursor = self.conn.cursor()
     cursor.execute(sql)
   return cursor
#

#
db = DB()
sql = "SELECT bla FROM foo"
data = db.query(sql)

for row in data:
    do_something(row)
#
```

But I'm always getting this:

```
#
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 124, in <module>
   run()
 File "teste.py", line 109, in run
   for row in data:
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 417, in next
   row = self.fetchone()
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 388, in fetchone
   r = self._fetch_row(1)
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 285, in _fetch_row
   return self._result.fetch_row(size, self._fetch_type)
   _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
    Exception _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') in <bound method SSCursor.__del__ of <MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor object at 0x7f7e3c8da410>> ignored
#
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Removing "cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor" from connect() call is enough. It's working pretty well now. Thanks.

Comment: i had the same problem, but i have ~1B rows of data so i want to use SSCursor to cache queried data on mysqld side instead of my python app.

Enlarged net_write_timeout to 1hr fixed the issue :)

Comment: To people getting here from Google: If you're using multi-threading, you'll need to give each thread its own connection.

Answer (score 51):

The mysql docs have a whole page dedicated to this error:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

of note are

- You can also get these errors if you send a query to the server that is incorrect or too large. If mysqld receives a packet that is too large or out of order, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. If you need big queries (for example, if you are working with big BLOB columns), you can increase the query limit by setting the server's max_allowed_packet variable, which has a default value of 1MB. You may also need to increase the maximum packet size on the client end. More information on setting the packet size is given in Section B.5.2.10, “Packet too large”.
- You can get more information about the lost connections by starting mysqld with the --log-warnings=2 option. This logs some of the disconnected errors in the hostname.err file

Comment: Another reason might be that mysqld is crashing.

Answer (score 38):

There are three ways to enlarge the max_allowed_packet of mysql server:

1. Change `max_allowed_packet=64M` in file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` on the mysql server machine and restart the server
2. Execute the sql on the mysql server: `set global max_allowed_packet=67108864;`
3. Python executes sql after connecting to the mysql:

```py
connection.execute('set max_allowed_packet=67108864')
```

Comment: max_allowed_packet is readonly, the first solution works for me.

Answer (score 17):

> You can also encounter this error with applications that fork child processes, all of which try to use the same connection to the MySQL server. This can be avoided by using a separate connection for each child process.

Forks might hit you. Beware not in this case though.

Comment: Yes this was the problem for me. I was using uwsgi to serve my flask app, and in the uwsi config file, i had the processes directive set to 5. I changed it to 1 and it worked, I don't understand the problem though. Shouldn't each process generate it's own connection?

Comment: @Rockstar5645 who did you solve this problem ?

Comment: @vishal I don't really remember, but it looks like I changed the processes directive from 5 to 1.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you close cursor before connection. I've resolved my problem with this:

```
if cur and con:                        
    cur.close() 
    con.close()
```

Comment: If you close the cursor and the connection before the connection, won't it not be able to connect in the first place?

Answer (score 10):

You need to increase the timeout on your connection. If you can't or don't want to do that for some reason, you could try calling:

```
data = db.query(sql).store_result()
```

This will fetch all the results immediately, then your connection won't time out halfway through iterating over them.

Comment: for reference and a permanent solution [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout)

Comment: also check [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6447452/1085495)

Answer (score 6):

I my case the reason for the

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

error was that parts of my table were **corrupted**. I was also not able to `mysqldump` my table because some rows broke it.
The error was not related to any memory issues etc. like mentioned above.

The nice thing was that MySQL returned me the row number which was the first what failed. It was something like

> mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table mytable at row: 12723

The solution was to copy the data into a new table. In my case I lost 10 rows of data because i had to skip these corrupted rows. First I created a "tmp" table with the schema of the old one. `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is your friend here. E.g.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mydatabase.mytable;
```

With the i created the new table. Let's call it *mytabletmp*. And then copy the rows you are able to copy via e.g.

```
insert into mysqltabletmp select * from mytable where id < 12723;
insert into mysqltabletmp select * from mytable where id > 12733;
```

After that drop old table, rename tmp-table to the old table name.

There are also [some nice Information from Peter](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/) regarding this problem.

Answer (score 4):

This was happening to me with mariadb because I made a `varchar(255)` column a `unique key`.. guess that's too heavy for a unique, as the insert was timing out.

Answer (score 4):

Multiprocessing and Django DB don't play well together.

I ended up closing Django DB connection first thing in the new process.

So that one will have no references to the connection used by the parent.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

multi_core_arg = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
n_cpu = 4
pool = Pool(n_cpu)
pool.map(_etl_, multi_core_arg)
pool.close()
pool.join()

def _etl_(x):
    from django.db import connection 
    connection.close() 
    print(x)
```

OR

`Process.start()` calls a function which starts with

Some other suggest to use

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
```

It solved my (2013, Lost connection) problem, but thread use GIL, when doing IO, to will release it when IO finish.

Comparatively, Process spawn a group of workers that communication each other, which may be slower.

I recommend you to time it.
A side tips is to use [joblib](http://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) which is backed by scikit-learn project.
some performance result shows it out perform the native Pool().. although it leave the responsibility to coder to verify the true run time cost.

Comment: > Multiprocessing and Django DB don't play well together.
So it is today, which is quite frustrating.

(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
(2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken Pipe'))")

(ಥ﹏ಥ)

Answer (score 4):

The same as @imxylz, but I had to use `mycursor.execute('set GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=67108864')`  as I got a read-only error without using the GLOBAL parameter.

```
mysql.connector.__version__
```

8.0.16

Answer (score 2):

Set the 'max_allowed_packet' setting to 64M and restart your MySql server. If that did not fixed your issues, the problem may lie elsewhere.

I've a multi-threaded PHP CLI application that does simultaneous queries and I recently noticed this issue. It's now obvious to me that MySql server consider all connections from the same IP as a 'single' connection and therefore drop all connections whenever a single query finishes.

I wonder though that is there a way to make MySql allow say 100 connections from the same IP and consider each connection as an individual connection.

Comment: I don't think your statement about "all connections from the same IP as a 'sing'e' connection" is correct. You may be seeing that because the mysql methods may be reusing a persistent connection between your PHP "threads".

Comment: "t's now obvious to me that MySql server consider all connections from the same IP as a 'single' connection " => this this of course just plain wrong, and can be very easily verified by launching ten parallel mysql client processes on the same box while monitoring mysql connections - each client will OF COURSE have it's own connection.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar problems too. In my case it was solved by getting the cursor in this way:

```
cursor = self.conn.cursor(buffered=True)
```

Comment: I was using mysql.connector instead of MySQLdb

Answer (score 2):

I wasted hours dealing with this problem and in the end I solved it by doing three things:

1. Making sure the MySQL **server** timeout and packet variables aren't set too low. To see what your global and session variables are set to, run:

```sql
SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';
```

For testing purposes, you can try:

```sql
SET SESSION interactive_timeout=31536000;
SET SESSION wait_timeout=31536000;
```

*Note: session variables only affect the current session. Global variables only affect new sessions i.e. if you're already connected, you'll need to disconnect and reconnect for the changes to affect your session.*

```sql
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
SET GLOBAL net_buffer_length=1048576;
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=31536000;
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=31536000;
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=31536000;
```

*Note: when the MySQL server is restarted, global settings will be reverted. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69993557/4409950).*

You can also set these variables in [`my.cnf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size).

2. Making sure the MySQL **client** timeout variables aren't set too low either. For example, [HeidiSQL](https://github.com/HeidiSQL/HeidiSQL)'s query timeout is set to 30 seconds by default (see the "Advanced" tab in the Session Manager).

You can also try setting `interactive_timeout` to 8 hours:

```sql
SET @@session.interactive_timeout = 28800;
```

3. Splitting up large files and long-running queries. If you're importing a very large SQL or CSV file, try splitting it into [16 mb chunks](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html). If you're executing a long-running query, maybe you could limit the number of rows you read/write at one time.

Bonus tip: ensure you have enough disk space and memory to run MySQL. It sounds basic but it's a potential source of issues.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if someone or something kills your connection using the [KILL command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/kill.html).

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I tried to update a table whose size on disk was bigger than the available disk space. The solution for me was simply to increase the available disk space.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I ran into this problem when sourcing an SQL dump which had placed the tables in the wrong order.  The CREATE in question included a CONSTRAINT ... REFERENCES that referenced a table that had not been created yet.

I located the table in question, and moved its CREATE statement to above the offending one, and the error disappeared.

The other error I encountered relating to this faulty dump was ERROR 1005/ errno: 150 -- "Can't create table" , again a matter of tables being created out of order.

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me when my `CONSTRAINT` name have the same name with other `CONSTRAINT` name.

Changing my `CONSTRAINT` name solved this.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem. Because of some other issues I had tried to add a `cnx.close()` line to my other functions. Instead, I removed all these extraneous closes and setup my class like this:

```
class DBase:

config = {
      'user': 'root',
      'password': '',
      'host': '127.0.0.1',
      'database': 'bio',
      'raise_on_warnings': True,
      'use_pure': False,
      }

def __init__(self):
    import mysql.connector
    self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**self.config)
    self.cur = self.cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
    print(self.cnx)
def __enter__(self):
    return DBase()

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.cnx.commit()
    if self.cnx:
        self.cnx.close()
```

Any function that is called within this class is connects, commits, and closes.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error with a "broken pipe" when I tried to do bulk inserts with millions of records. I ended up solving this by chunking my data into smaller batch sizes and then running an executemany command with the mysql cursor for each of the inserts I needed to do. This solved the problem and didn't seem to affect the performance in any noticeable way.

eg.

```
def chunks(data):
    for i in range(0, len(data), CHUNK_SIZE):
        yield data[i:i + CHUNK_SIZE]


def bulk_import(update_list):
    new_list = list(chunks(update_list))
    for batch in new_list:
         cursor.execute(#SQL STATEMENT HERE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see my answer followed for similar problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69610550/16647254

use lock to solve this problem

```
lock.acquire()
mysqlhelper.getconn()
result_db_num = mysqlhelper.update(sql, [businessid, md5_id])
mysqlhelper.end()
mysqlhelper.dispose()
lock.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and wrestled for many hours, experimenting with LOTS of different solutions.  What finally worked for me was this. The code opens a 10 connection pool initially, then mysql.connector serves up connections from the pool with get_connection().

```
class DB:
    connection = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn()

    def conn(self):
        try:
            if not self.connection:
                self.connection = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(user='web', password='mypasswd',
                                                                              host='prod', database='myelection',
                                                                              autocommit=True, pool_size=10,
                                                                              buffered=True)
            return self.connection.get_connection()

        except mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError as err:
            print("can't connect to mysql ", err)

        except mysql.connector.DatabaseError as err:
            print("database error: ", err)

        except Exception as err:
            print("unknown db exception: ", err)

        print("exiting from conn() with error.")
        exit()

    # Make sure your class methods open, then automatically 
    # close the connections and the cursors.
    def new_polling_place(self, pp_name):
        #  cur = self.conn().cursor(dictionary=True)
        with self.conn() as con:
            with con.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO pollingplace (pp_name) VALUES (%s)", [pp_name])
                return cur.lastrowid
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a new column is added to the table which is not nullable but existing records of that table don't have that column value, in that case when i am trying to retrieve data from that table, It is giving this error.
Putting a default value solved this

Answer (score -1):

This very same situation happened to me while working with `mariadb` , `sqlalchemy` and `pandas` and just like `@iamapotatoe` above I also created a function to break up the dataframe into chunks and port them over to the sql database bit by bit.
This can be utilized especially if changing the `max_allowed_packet` in the mysql config option doesn't work for you .

```
def load_large_df(table_name,df_to_load,batch_size,engine):
    df_to_load = df_to_load.dropna(how='all')
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table_name}")
        rows = df_to_load.shape[0]
        batch = int(rows/batch_size)
        

        strt = 0
        while strt < rows:
            df = df_to_load[strt:].head(batch)
            df.to_sql(table_name,con=conn,if_exists='append')
            strt += batch
```

Comment: Pandas already provides a dedicated (and optimized) parameter `chunksize`  to import a large dataframe in chunks.

Answer (score -4):

very simple to solve, go to the control panel of you phpadmin and click on config/then edit the .ini file you see. look for port 3306 if that's not the port you are using for your connection change 3306 to the port you are using. on your login screen just put localhost for your server, your port if its not the default or if you did not change the file name my.ini in sql configuration leavit as is. then put your username:root or the one you created then the password:1234 or the one you assigned. if you are connecting localy, do not check the url option. then type the name of the database you want to edit. note: once you are connected you will see the list of databases you have on your server or the server you are connecting to.

Comment: remember to use the % to give the user the privilege of  universal access to your table and databases

Comment: I don't know how this answer is even related. OP was trying to ask why he is losing connection when executing a query.

Comment: This answer is Off-Topic.