# Python lose Mysql Server connection

Tags: android, python, mysql

i'm connecting python to mySqL Databases and sending things from android two Double values to be store in Mysql then i get this error

```
enter code here
 Exception in thread :
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 530, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
  File "C:\Users\ingy\Desktop\New folder (2)\sssssss.py", line 64, in run
self.pacman()
 File "C:\Users\ingy\Desktop\New folder (2)\sssssss.py", line 45, in pacman
x.execute("UPDATE location SET x='%s'"%(x1))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 174, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in  defaulterrorhandler
 raise errorclass, errorvalue
 OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

Now

```
   enter code here
         OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I do, in our case it only goes away once in the worst case and throws a different error, so we don't get infinite recurision.

```
def query(self, sql, parameters=None):
    cursor = self.db.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql, parameters)
        return cursor
    except mysql.connector.Error as ex:
        if ex.errno == 2006: # mysql has gone away
            cursor.close()
            self.connect()
            return self.query(sql, parameters)
        raise ex
```

Comment: OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') so i get this error any hlelp

Comment: 2013 is a bit worse of a problem, seems like the connection between your webserver and database is not stable.  In my case we would fix the connection.  But if this is acceptable to you, you can always add `if ex[0] == 2006 or ex[0] == 2013:`

Comment: This works for me .....thanks.....a...lot....

Answer (score 1):

This usually takes place when your application is idling for too long and not communicating with MySQL. You can either:

- increase the mysql servers connection timeout (in your case the `wait_timeout`)
- send out dummy MySQL queries from time to time `SELECT 1`

If you have access to MySQL's connections settings definitely go with the first one.

Comment: how to do wait time in python

Comment: That is the mysql server configuration flag. The only thing you can do straight from python is the second option.