# MySQL Lost connection to MySQL server during query when importing medium size file

Tags: mysql

Im trying to import a table with hundred thousand rows. I have already increased the following configurations:

```
sort_buffer_size = 2097152to 4194304
read_buffer_size = 131072to 262144
read_rnd_buffer_size = 262144 to 524288
join_buffer_size = 131072 to 262144
key_buffer_size = 16777216 to 33554432
innodb_buffer_pool_size  = 134217728 to 1G
```

I have 4GB memory. I am trying to import 145MB SQL file. The error is

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 145: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Comment: Whats the value of max_allowed_packet in your settings? Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7006296/3810847

Comment: max_allowed_packet=1073741824