# Opencart, Error No: 2013, Error: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.3

I currently working on opencart 2.3.0.2, occasionally I got a Fatal error when loading the site, and after reloading the same, the error is not happened.

*error is:*

**Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Error No: 2013
UPDATE oc_customer SET language_id = '1', ip = '201.82.47.97' WHERE customer_id = '1'' in /home/content/11/4759612/html/bline/system/library/db/mysqli.php:40 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/11/4759612/html/bline/system/library/db.php(16): DB\MySQLi->query('UPDATE oc_custo...', Array) #1 /home/content/11/4759612/html/bline/system/library/cart/customer.php(34): DB->query('UPDATE oc_custo...') #2**

how to fix these

Thanking in advance

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516943/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: You aren't showing the query