# How to take backup of a database which has table size 105 GB?

Tags: mysql, backup

There is a database in MYSQL InnoDB engine. When I take backup of my database which is about 150 GB by mysqldump command on linux server. I get the error message

> mysqldump Lost connection.

There is a table of size 105 GB and about 420 000 000 rows and about 100 000 rows inserting average per hour. I got that error when backup is running at this table. How to take backup and what is the foolproof process?

Comment: This is a frequent question. The most common solution is to increase your `max_allowed_packet` at least as large as your largest row of data. If you search Stack Overflow or dba.stackexchange.com for "mysqldump lost connection" you will find many past discussions.

Comment: mysqldump for a table this size is going to be very slow. Any reason you could not use xtrabackup?

Comment: Could you confirm if the solution bellow is solving your issue ?

Comment: I have changed mysqldump --single-transaction. It seems it works

Answer (score 7):

Really similar to [Lost connection to MySQL server during query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6516943/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query) & https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97846/mysqldump-error-2013

Add those parameters in your `mysqldump` command line:

```
--max_allowed-packet=1G --net-read-timeout=7200 --net-write-timeout=7200 --net-buffer-length=32704
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a backup in parts using a WHERE clause to split it to several files.

You should look for an index or perhaps use the primary key and use several mysqldump commands. Note that the data will not be a snapshot of the whole table at the same time.

```
mysqldump -u root -p  dbName tableName --where="id>=10000 AND id<20000" > dbName_tableName_10_20.sql
```

Consider splitting the table on the future for easier maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

The "Lost Connection" problem is caused by too much data through the dumping channel - you need to increase `max_allowed_packet` in my.cnf.

I had this pointed out to me a long time ago, but now rereading the docs I'm not too sure it applies. You might try it, anyway, or use it for further research:

> Note that `mysqldump` will build special multiple-`INSERT` clauses which might exceed the buffer length. You may then need to resort to `--skip-extended-insert` (which will greatly slow down restore) when backing up.

The docs say:

> net_buffer_length
>      The initial size of the buffer for client/server communication. When creating multiple-row INSERT statements (as with the --extended-insert or --opt option), mysqldump creates rows up to net_buffer_length bytes long. If you increase this variable, ensure that the MySQL server net_buffer_length system variable has a value at least this large. 
>   [...] 
>    max_allowed_packet
>    The maximum size of one packet **or any generated/intermediate string**, or any parameter sent by the mysql_stmt_send_long_data() C API function. The default is 4MB.
>
> The packet message buffer is initialized to net_buffer_length bytes, **but can grow up to max_allowed_packet** bytes when needed.

However, backing up will lock the database (or the tables) and cause service problems. So you might be better off by, first, setting up *replication*, so that the slave is kept in a consistent state by continuous updates from its master. When you need to backup, you [lock the slave and set it to read only](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/replication-solutions-backups.html), then can either run a mysqldump or just back up the binary data (which the manual recommends for larger databases).

Comment: --max_allowed-packet=1G  is already exists. Now I have added mysqldump --single-transaction. It seems it works.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this two thing

One Configuration :

```
configured max_allowed_packet to 1024M
configured net_read_timeout to 7200
configured net_write_timeout to 7200
```

Second :

```
mysqldump -u root --skip-extended-insert -p <DB> DB.sql
```