# Lost connection to MySQL server during query - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I just made a script in codeigniter which fetches emails and displays them with php imap.
It fetches 500 mails at once no problem.
If i try to fetch about 2000 mails at once, it throws an error.

> A Database Error Occurred
>   Error Number: 2013
>
> Lost connection to MySQL server during query
>
> SELECT GET_LOCK('77dfd862ae2b7bedaec521bc4c3651952b56e6c9', 300) AS
>   ci_session_lock
>
> Filename: libraries/Session/drivers/Session_database_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 358

This project is live on hostgator. I am not sure if it has mysql workbench or not.
I have no idea where it comes from and why.
I have done nothing with mysql in codeigniter before.

I do not know which file to edit and where to start. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Comment: I do not know where mysql workbench exists. I have never used it. Please help.

Comment: Try this method : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7006296/8566549

Comment: @HastaDhana As mentioned in the answer, where can i find the "my.cnf / my.ini"
or where do i put the "mysql -u <user> " command. My project is live on hostgator.