# How can I fix this sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

While executing below query facing "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" error.
how can I fix it?

```
SELECT * 
FROM firmalar,
     musterisahipleri,
     notlar 
WHERE firmalar.firmaID NOT IN (
       SELECT m2.firmaID 
       FROM notlar AS n2,
            musterisahipleri AS m2
       WHERE n2.eklemeTarihi > '2013-03-24'
   ) 
   AND musterisahipleri.firmaID = firmalar.firmaID 
   AND notlar.ilgiliID = musterisahipleri.userID;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The error looks to me like a timeout. You seem to have a HUGE join in your subquery, perhaps if you sort that out the whole thing will complete faster?

Comment: This question is very vague... what kind of data is contained within your database? Seems like your query is processing a large dataset and times out? Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884859/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: As others have said, likely a time out. Hard to see where though from waht you have posted. The table structures (or relevant bits), any indexes, and an Explain might enable us to help you. Along with using proper syntax..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're timing out because you're using inefficient nested subqueries.

This will perform better:

EDIT: Per your last comment, this query will return you `firmalar` records that have no `notlar` records added since '2013-03-24'... it then joins those results on `musterisahipleri` and `notlar` again to get associated reps and notes (if applicable)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT f.* 
    FROM firmalar AS f
    LEFT JOIN musterisahipleri AS m
        ON m.firmaID = f.firmaID
    LEFT JOIN notlar AS n
        ON n.ilgiliID = m.userID
        AND n.eklemeTarihi > '2013-03-24'
    GROUP BY f.firmaID
    HAVING MAX(n.ilgiliID) IS NULL
) AS f
    LEFT JOIN musterisahipleri AS m
        ON m.firmaID = f.firmaID
    LEFT JOIN notlar AS n
        ON n.ilgiliID = m.userID
```

You should also ensure you have indexes on the columns you're joining on, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE firmalar ADD INDEX (firmaID);
ALTER TABLE musterisahipleri ADD INDEX (firmaID);
ALTER TABLE musterisahipleri ADD INDEX (userID);
ALTER TABLE notlar ADD INDEX (ilgiliID);
```

Comment: Swift, I was just typing up something like this.

Comment: Thanks but with this query I got Null "notlar"

Comment: This is not the same query as the original one. The original one excludes all results with a date greater than '2013-03-24'. In your query, you're doing the inverse

Comment: magmedya.net/2.png 
magmedya.net/3.png

Comment: @UgurOzer - I edited the query in my answer.  Have another go?

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis - Yeah, I noticed that.  The original query was packed into one line, which made it hard to read.

Comment: Actually I need to list "firmalar" which one not added at least 2 months. With this list I need to add latest notes of this "firmalar" called "notlar" with "musterisahipleri". With my English I think it became a little bit complicated. sorry.

Comment: You need the firma, the musterisahipleri, and the notlar?  what is the musterisahipleri?  Does each table have a priimary key?  If so, what are they called?  Thanks.

Comment: Ok I'll try to explain like that. I have 3 tables. Firma (Companies), musterisahipleri (Representives) and Notlar (notes). you can find all these tables at http://magmedya.net/1.png - http://magmedya.net/2.png and http://magmedya.net/3.png. So I'm trying to list Notlar (notes) which one not added on last 2 months. And I want to add Firmalar (Companies) and their representives (Musterisahipleri) to this list.

Comment: Ok, that's a little more complex.  Give me a sec.

Comment: eklemeTarihi means notes' add date in musterisahipleri Table

Comment: Surely. Thanks a lot Steven. I'm waiting for 15 rep. to vote up your answer :)

Comment: It comes with this error 
"#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Yup, added the alias (oops!)

Comment: I know it started be disturbing but it comes with this error this time. "#1054 - Unknown column 'n.ilgiliID' in 'on clause'"

Comment: Make sure you got my latest edit.  I had incorrectly aliased notlar as `n2` in one of my edits.

Comment: I really shame of my lack of knowledge but it is like that. http://magmedya.net/4.png   Isn't it your latest edit?

Comment: Yes, that's my latest edit.  But now I'm confused.  Isn't there an `ilgiliID` on the `notlar` table?

Comment: That's really odd.  Try running just the inner query first, to see if the error is there or on the outer query. 
    `SELECT f.* FROM firmalar AS f LEFT JOIN musterisahipleri AS m ON m.firmaID = f.firmaID LEFT JOIN notlar AS n ON n.ilgiliID = m.userID AND n.eklemeTarihi > '2013-03-24' GROUP BY f.firmaID HAVING n.ilgiliID IS NULL`

Comment: PS - note a new addition of a `MAX()` function in the `HAVING` clause

Comment: Still same :( I think there is a problem about me. Really thanks a lot. You don't have to pore upon this problem anymore...

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up `not in` subqueries in older versions by MySQL by replacing them with `not exists`.  The appropriate indexes definitely help (as recommended by Steven Moseley.

This version moves the joins into the `from` clause and replaces the `not in` with `not exists`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM firmalar join
     musterisahipleri 
     on musterisahipleri.firmaID = firmalar.firmaID join
     notlar 
     on notlar.ilgiliID = musterisahipleri.userID
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  FROM notlar n2 join
                       musterisahipleri m2
                       on n2.ilgiliID = m3.userID
                 WHERE n2.eklemeTarihi > '2013-03-24' and
                       firmalar.firmaID = m2.firmaID
                )
```

In writing this, I realize that the problem with the original query is that the tables in the `not in` subquery were not properly joined together.  This yet again emphasizes why proper join syntax (using the `join` and `on` keywords in the `from` clause) is superior to implicit joins in the `where` clause.