# Threading and SQLAlchemy Sessions

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I know this question has been asked a few times, but I'm still unsure about the usage of `scoped_session` with threading. Basically, I have an application with 10 worker threads. I have one `Engine` with a connection pool size of 11. Each thread has it's own session, and no information needs to be shared across the threads' sessions (if they could, that would be nice, but I have created a workaround). Finally, I am using the SQLAlchemy Core in the main thread for complex SQL statements, which is why I have 11 threads in the connection pool.

I am using MySQL and my `pool_recycle` is set to 3600. I keep getting errors:

`(OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')`

This has never happened when I had just one worker thread, even without any `pool_recycle` set. I have a very basic understanding of MySQL and SQLAlchemy, so I am not sure if my issues stem from my use of SQLAlchemy or MySQL (or none of the above).

Here is my setup:

```
common = Common()
class Common(object):
    def __init__(self):
    ...
         self.engine = create_engine(
            '%(type)s://%(username)s:%(password)s@%(endpoint)s:%(port)s/%(name)s?charset=utf8' % {
              'type': config.get('db_type'),
              'username': 'foo',
              'password': 'bar',
              'endpoint': config.get('db_endpoint'),
              'port': str(config.get('db_port')),
              'name': config.get('db_name'),
            },
        encoding='utf-8',
        pool_size=config.get('num_workers') + 1,
        pool_recycle=3600,
    )
    self.session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
```

Each worker calls `self.session = common.session()` and uses this session throughout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lost connection to MySQL server during query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884859/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Comment: Where's the `scoped_session` used in here? maybe try : `self.session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=self.engine))` and then do : `self.session(); self.session.query....; self.session.remove()`

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation you should use different instance of engine for every subprocess, in your case you have one engine for all subprocesses, because connection pool between subprocesses cannot be shared (as i understand).

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/connections.html