# MYSQL like causing Lost Connection

Tags: mysql

I am running this query

```
SELECT 
    friends.*, users.username, users.profile, users_groups.id
FROM 
    friends, users, users_groups 
WHERE 
    friends.uid=$logged_id AND friends.who=users.id 
    AND
        (
            users.username LIKE '%$search%' OR
            users.first_name LIKE '%$search%' OR
            users.last_name LIKE '%$search%'
        )
LIMIT 
    $start, $min
```

however I am receiving this:

```
Error Number: 2013

Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

If I remove the LIKE statements from the query it works

Comment: I like the way you style your SQL! :)

Comment: [This answer can help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884859/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a large table and LIKEs provoke a timeout.