# Process very large 900M row MySQL table line by line with Python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python, bigdata

I often need to process several hundred million rows of a MySQL table on a line by line basis using Python.  I want a script that is robust and does not need to be monitored.

Below I pasted a script that classifying the language of the message field in my row.  It utilizes the sqlalchemy and MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor modules.  Unfortunately this script consistently throws a **'Lost connection to MySQL server during query'** error after 4840 rows when I run remotely and 42000 rows when I run locally.

Also, I have checked and max_allowed_packet = 32M on my MySQL server's /etc/mysql/my.cnf file as per the answers to this stackoverflow question [Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884859/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Any advice for either fixing this error, or using another approach to use Python for processing very large MySQL files in a robust way would be much appreciated!

```
import sqlalchemy
import MySQLdb.cursors
import langid

schema = "twitterstuff"
table = "messages_en" #900M row table
engine_url = "mysql://myserver/{}?charset=utf8mb4&read_default_file=~/.my.cnf".format(schema)
db_eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_url, connect_args={'cursorclass': MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor} )
langid.set_languages(['fr', 'de'])

print "Executing input query..."
data_iter = db_eng.execute("SELECT message_id, message FROM {} WHERE langid_lang IS NULL LIMIT 10000".format(table))

def process(inp_iter):
    for item in inp_iter:
        item = dict(item)
        (item['langid_lang'], item['langid_conf']) = langid.classify(item['message'])
        yield item

def update_table(update_iter):
    count = 0;
    for item in update_iter:
        count += 1;
        if count%10 == 0:
            print "{} rows processed".format(count)
        lang = item['langid_lang']
        conf = item['langid_conf']
        message_id = item['message_id']
        db_eng.execute("UPDATE {} SET langid_lang = '{}', langid_conf = {} WHERE message_id = {}".format(table, lang, conf, message_id))

data_iter_upd = process(data_iter)

print "Begin processing..."
update_table(data_iter_upd)
```

Comment: Sounds like a timeout to me.  Have you tried tweaking [`wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and/or [`net_write_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_write_timeout)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to MySQLdb developer Andy Dustman](http://mysql-python.blogspot.com/2010/02/asynchronous-programming-and-mysqldb.html),

> [When using SSCursor,] no new queries can be issued on the connection until
>       the entire result set has been fetched.

That post says that if you issue another query you will get a "commands out of sequence" error, which is not the error you are seeing. So I am not sure that the following will necessarily fix your problem. Nevertheless, it might be worth trying to remove `SSCursor` from your code and use the simpler default `Cursor` just to test if that is the source of the problem.

You could, for example, use `LIMIT chunksize OFFSET n` in your `SELECT` statement
to loop through the data set in chunks:

```
import sqlalchemy
import MySQLdb.cursors
import langid
import itertools as IT
chunksize = 1000

def process(inp_iter):
    for item in inp_iter:
        item = dict(item)
        (item['langid_lang'], item['langid_conf']) = langid.classify(item['message'])
        yield item

def update_table(update_iter, engine):
    for count, item in enumerate(update_iter):
        if count%10 == 0:
            print "{} rows processed".format(count)
        lang = item['langid_lang']
        conf = item['langid_conf']
        message_id = item['message_id']
        engine.execute(
            "UPDATE {} SET langid_lang = '{}', langid_conf = {} WHERE message_id = {}"
            .format(table, lang, conf, message_id))

schema = "twitterstuff"
table = "messages_en" #900M row table
engine_url = ("mysql://myserver/{}?charset=utf8mb4&read_default_file=~/.my.cnf"
              .format(schema))

db_eng = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_url)
langid.set_languages(['fr', 'de'])

for offset in IT.count(start=0, step=chunksize):
    print "Executing input query..."
    result = db_eng.execute(
        "SELECT message_id, message FROM {} WHERE langid_lang IS NULL LIMIT {} OFFSET {}"
        .format(table, chunksize, offset))
    result = list(result)
    if not result: break
    data_iter_upd = process(result)

    print "Begin processing..."
    update_table(data_iter_upd, db_eng)
```