# WordPress database error Lost connection to MySQL server during query for query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

WordPress database error Lost connection to MySQL server during query for query

```
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name =
'_wp_session_3a7889923217a8890a3a44f073b9f57f' LIMIT 1 
made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), 
require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), 
do_action('plugins_loaded'), call_user_func_array, NF_Session->init,
WP_Session::get_instance, WP_Session->__construct, 
WP_Session->read_data, get_option
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Any improvements to formatting of the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost connection to MySQL server during query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884859/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)