# Mysql down because of chinese language maybe

Tags: mysql, wordpress

MySQL version 5.7.19

Error:

```
[Fri Sep 15 14:40:25.841726 2017] [:error] [pid 17891] [client 125.39.57.36:56477] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): (HY000/2013): Lost connection to MySQL server during query in /home/dsh.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877

[Fri Sep 15 14:40:25.867495 2017] [:error] [pid 17891] [client 125.39.57.36:56477] WordPress database error Lost connection to MySQL server during query for query \n\t\t\t\t\tSELECT DISTINCT \n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.id,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.name,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.context,\n\t\t\t\t\t\tst.status,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.gettext_context, \n\t\t\t\t\t\tst.value AS tra,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.value AS orig\n\t\t\t\t\tFROM wep_icl_string_pages sp\n\t\t\t\t\tINNER JOIN wep_icl_string_urls su\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON su.id = sp.url_id\n\t\t\t\t\tINNER JOIN wep_icl_strings s\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON s.id = sp.string_id\n\t\t\t\t\tLEFT JOIN wep_icl_string_translations st\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON s.id=st.string_id\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAND st.language=su.language\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAND s.language!=su.language\n\t\t\t\t\tWHERE (su.language='en' and su.url='/') or (su.language='en' and su.url IS NULL)\n\t\t\t\t\t made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), WP_Locale->__construct, WP_Locale->init, __, translate, apply_filters('gettext'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, icl_sw_filters_gettext, icl_translate, WPML_Register_String_Filter->translate_by_name_and_context, WPML_ST_DB_Cache->get_translation, WPML_ST_Page_Translations_Cached_Persist->get_translations_for_page, WPML_ST_Page_Translations_Persist->get_translations_for_page


[Fri Sep 15 14:40:37.146892 2017] [:error] [pid 17884] [client 111.30.137.187:54067] WordPress database error Lost connection to MySQL server during query for query \tSELECT element_id, language_code\n\t\t\t\t\t\tFROM wep_icl_translations\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWHERE trid =\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(SELECT trid\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t FROM wep_icl_translations\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t WHERE element_type = 'post_page'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t AND element_id = (SELECT option_value\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   FROM wep_options\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   WHERE option_name='page_on_front'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   LIMIT 1))\n\t\t\t\t\t\t made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, WP_Query->parse_query, get_option, apply_filters('pre_option_page_on_front'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, SitePress->pre_option_page_on_front, WPML_Pre_Option_Page->get

[Fri Sep 15 14:40:37.163339 2017] [:error] [pid 17886] [client 123.126.118.139:46358] WordPress database error Lost connection to MySQL server during query for query \tSELECT element_id, language_code\n\t\t\t\t\t\tFROM wep_icl_translations\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWHERE trid =\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(SELECT trid\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t FROM wep_icl_translations\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t WHERE element_type = 'post_page'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t AND element_id = (SELECT option_value\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   FROM wep_options\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   WHERE option_name='page_on_front'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   LIMIT 1))\n\t\t\t\t\t\t made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, WP_Query->parse_query, get_option, apply_filters('pre_option_page_on_front'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, SitePress->pre_option_page_on_front, WPML_Pre_Option_Page->get

[Fri Sep 15 14:40:37.163902 2017] [:error] [pid 17885] [client 111.30.131.238:53414] WordPress database error Lost connection to MySQL server during query for query \tSELECT element_id, language_code\n\t\t\t\t\t\tFROM wep_icl_translations\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWHERE trid =\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(SELECT trid\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t FROM wep_icl_translations\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t WHERE element_type = 'post_page'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t AND element_id = (SELECT option_value\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   FROM wep_options\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   WHERE option_name='page_on_front'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   LIMIT 1))\n\t\t\t\t\t\t made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, WP_Query->parse_query, get_option, apply_filters('pre_option_page_on_front'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, SitePress->pre_option_page_on_front, WPML_Pre_Option_Page->get

[Fri Sep 15 14:40:37.164819 2017] [:error] [pid 17887] [client 61.49.56.47:42110] WordPress database error Lost connection to MySQL server during query for query \tSELECT element_id, language_code\n\t\t\t\t\t\tFROM wep_icl_translations\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWHERE trid =\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t(SELECT trid\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t FROM wep_icl_translations\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t WHERE element_type = 'post_page'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t AND element_id = (SELECT option_value\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   FROM wep_options\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   WHERE option_name='page_on_front'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   LIMIT 1))\n\t\t\t\t\t\t made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts, WP_Query->parse_query, get_option, apply_filters('pre_option_page_on_front'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, SitePress->pre_option_page_on_front, WPML_Pre_Option_Page->get

[Fri Sep 15 14:40:37.248191 2017] [:error] [pid 17907] [client 111.30.141.105:34515] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): (HY000/2013): Lost connection to MySQL server during query in /home/dsh.com/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1877

[Fri Sep 15 14:40:37.546416 2017] [:error] [pid 17940] [client 111.30.141.104:46769] WordPress database error Lost connection to MySQL server during query for query \n\t\t\t\t\tSELECT DISTINCT \n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.id,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.name,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.context,\n\t\t\t\t\t\tst.status,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.gettext_context, \n\t\t\t\t\t\tst.value AS tra,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.value AS orig\n\t\t\t\t\tFROM wep_icl_string_pages sp\n\t\t\t\t\tINNER JOIN wep_icl_string_urls su\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON su.id = sp.url_id\n\t\t\t\t\tINNER JOIN wep_icl_strings s\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON s.id = sp.string_id\n\t\t\t\t\tLEFT JOIN wep_icl_string_translations st\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON s.id=st.string_id\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAND st.language=su.language\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAND s.language!=su.language\n\t\t\t\t\tWHERE (su.language='en' and su.url='/') or (su.language='en' and su.url IS NULL)\n\t\t\t\t\t made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), WP_Locale->__construct, WP_Locale->init, __, translate, apply_filters('gettext'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, icl_sw_filters_gettext, icl_translate, WPML_Register_String_Filter->translate_by_name_and_context, WPML_ST_DB_Cache->get_translation, WPML_ST_Page_Translations_Cached_Persist->get_translations_for_page, WPML_ST_Page_Translations_Persist->get_translations_for_page

[Fri Sep 15 14:40:37.548473 2017] [:error] [pid 17941] [client 112.65.193.15:41552] WordPress\xe6\x95\xb0\xe6\x8d\xae\xe5\xba\x93\xe6\x9f\xa5\xe8\xaf\xa2\n\t\t\t\t\tSELECT DISTINCT \n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.id,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.name,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.context,\n\t\t\t\t\t\tst.status,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.gettext_context, \n\t\t\t\t\t\tst.value AS tra,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.value AS orig\n\t\t\t\t\tFROM wep_icl_string_pages sp\n\t\t\t\t\tINNER JOIN wep_icl_string_urls su\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON su.id = sp.url_id\n\t\t\t\t\tINNER JOIN wep_icl_strings s\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON s.id = sp.string_id\n\t\t\t\t\tLEFT JOIN wep_icl_string_translations st\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON s.id=st.string_id\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAND st.language=su.language\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAND s.language!=su.language\n\t\t\t\t\tWHERE (su.language='zh-hans' and su.url='/zh-hans/custom_events/equis%e9%85%92%e5%90%a7%e9%9a%86%e9%87%8d%e5%bc%80%e5%b9%95') or (su.language='zh-hans' and su.url IS NULL)\n\t\t\t\t\t\xe6\x97\xb6\xe5\x8f\x91\xe7\x94\x9fLost connection to MySQL server during query\xe9\x94\x99\xe8\xaf\xaf\xef\xbc\x8c\xe8\xbf\x99\xe6\x98\xaf\xe7\x94\xb1require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), WP_Locale->__construct, WP_Locale->init, __, translate, apply_filters('gettext'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, icl_sw_filters_gettext, icl_translate, WPML_Register_String_Filter->translate_by_name_and_context, WPML_ST_DB_Cache->get_translation, WPML_ST_Page_Translations_Cached_Persist->get_translations_for_page, WPML_ST_Page_Translations_Persist->get_translations_for_page\xe6\x9f\xa5\xe8\xaf\xa2\xe7\x9a\x84\xe3\x80\x82, referer: https://m.sogou.com/web/searchList.jsp?uID=HGHnQBYb1jn6MZnw&v=5&dp=1&e=1427&de=1&pid=sogou-clse-2996962656838a97&w=1278&t=1505457569445&s_t=1505457585463&s_from=result_up&htprequery=equis%E9%85%92%E5%90%A7&keyword=equis%E9%85%92%E5%90%A7&pg=webSearchList&sugct=0&sugri=1&sourceid=sugg&sugoq=equis&sugn=5&suguuid=f4fd7139-d195-45f4-ba59-125c7078ccc8&sugsuv=c7f6d6271727f247197063a73eebad69&sugtime=1505457585502

[Fri Sep 15 14:40:37.699627 2017] [:error] [pid 17907] [client 111.30.141.105:34515] WordPress database error Lost connection to MySQL server during query for query \n\t\t\t\t\tSELECT DISTINCT \n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.id,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.name,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.context,\n\t\t\t\t\t\tst.status,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.gettext_context, \n\t\t\t\t\t\tst.value AS tra,\n\t\t\t\t\t\ts.value AS orig\n\t\t\t\t\tFROM wep_icl_string_pages sp\n\t\t\t\t\tINNER JOIN wep_icl_string_urls su\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON su.id = sp.url_id\n\t\t\t\t\tINNER JOIN wep_icl_strings s\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON s.id = sp.string_id\n\t\t\t\t\tLEFT JOIN wep_icl_string_translations st\n\t\t\t\t\t\tON s.id=st.string_id\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAND st.language=su.language\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tAND s.language!=su.language\n\t\t\t\t\tWHERE (su.language='en' and su.url='/') or (su.language='en' and su.url IS NULL)\n\t\t\t\t\t made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), WP_Locale->__construct, WP_Locale->init, __, translate, apply_filters('gettext'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, icl_sw_filters_gettext, icl_translate, WPML_Register_String_Filter->translate_by_name_and_context, WPML_ST_DB_Cache->get_translation, WPML_ST_Page_Translations_Cached_Persist->get_translations_for_page, WPML_ST_Page_Translations_Persist->get_translations_for_page
```

whenever mysql is down this kind of error generates in apache error_log.

can anyone please give advise what is wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884859/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Comment: In short, I think your queries may be too big/long

Comment: share your select query

Comment: @KMS this is wordpress