# 2013 Lost connection to MySQLserver during query

Tags: mysql

i use this sql statement will report error:

```
SELECT case_option.plan_id AS plan_id,case_option.case_id AS case_id,options.option_name AS option_name,case_option.option_value as option_value,options.option_type AS option_type,options.option_or_env AS option_or_env  FROM case_option left join options on case_option.option_id = options.id where case_option.plan_id =90913 and case_option.case_id=30126
```

but use this is not report error：

```
SELECT case_option.plan_id AS plan_id,case_option.case_id AS case_id,options.option_name AS option_name,case_option.option_value as option_value,options.option_type AS option_type,options.option_or_env AS option_or_env  FROM case_option left join options on case_option.option_id = options.id where case_option.plan_id =90913 and case_option.case_id=30126
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884859/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Comment: Make sure you have 1 index on your 2 columns: `plan_id` and `case_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Check net_read_timeout value into mysql. You can set using below parameter.

SET @@local.net_read_timeout=360;

Also check max_allowed_packet value into mysql configuration file

Comment: i hava set net_read_timeout=360 and max_allowed_packet =1024*1024*1024,but do not work