# Python solving _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away') when using db models

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

So our python program is running into these errors `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`. The problem is that the program accesses the db, hen does a lot of crawling to come back with the results after the `mysql connection timeout` ... and then its too late.

By logic there are 2 solutions

- increase  `mysql connection timeout` but this is no option
- have python check for an open connection, and if closed then re-open it

Some solutions have been found and sound clear [possible solution](https://support.prodi.gy/t/peewee-operationalerror-mysql-server-has-gone-away/308/5) and here [about closing and opening cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884859/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query).

However we are using models from django .. and I dont know where to implement logic for a `check for a connection and reconnect of the connectin is lost` check.

**question**: Where and how can I implement the described logic to re-connect to a lost db connection when using models? (is there some kind of **INIT** or **CONNECT** event to access)

Sample code

```
from django.db import models

class Domain(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: How are you doing the crawling? Are you running it as part of a view and waiting for that view to return, or otherwise backgrounding the task using a message queue or possibly issuing an RPC to something like scrapyd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that wont be fixed as you can see here in the [Django docs](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21597#comment:29)
for the workaround you just have to close the connection if your program is going to be idle for a long time.

```
from django.db import connection
# DO SOMETHING TO THE DATABASE
connection.close()
```

Comment: HOw would we add this if using db models? for example we would define a model and call it in the code using `brand = Brand.objects.get(code=spider.brand_code)`

Answer (score 0):

If you close your connection, django will automatically re-open it if it needs to query the database.

So if you know that the problem comes in some function, wether a view or not, you can close the connection right before or at the beginning of that function:

```
from django.db import connection 
...
connection.close()
```