# MySQLConnector (Python): New DB connection for each query vs. one single connection

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python, database-cursor

I have this problem: I'm writing some Python scripts and while, up until now, I had no problems at all using a single MySQLConnector connection throughout the entire script (only closing it at the end of the script), lately I'm having some problems.

If I create a connection at the beginning of the script, something like (ignore the security concerns, I know):

```
db_conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='myPassword', host='127.0.0.1', database='my_db', autocommit=True)
```

and then always use it like:

```
db_conn.cursor(buffered=True).execute(...)
```

or fetch and other methods, I will get errors like:

```
Failed executing the SQL query: MySQL Connection not available.
```

OR

```
Failed executing the SQL query: No result set to fetch from.
```

OR

```
OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

The code is correct, I just don't understand why this happens. Maybe because I'm concurrently running the same function multiple times (tried with 2), in async, so maybe the concurrent access to the cursor causes this?

I found someone fixed it by using a different DB connection every time ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60960135/14690484)).

I tried to create a new connection for every single query to the DB and now there are no errors at all. It works fine but it seems an overkill. Imagine calling the async function 10 or 100 times...there would be a lot of DB connections created. Will it cause problems? Will it run out of memory? And, also, I guess it will slow down.

Is there a way to solve it by keeping the same connection for all the queries? Why does that happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL is a stateful protocol (more like ftp than http in this way). This means if you are running multiple async threads that are sending and receiving packets on the same MySQL connection, the protocol can't handle that. The server and client will get confused, because messages will arrive in the wrong order.

What I mean is if different async routines are trying to use the database connection at the same time, you can easily get into trouble:

```
async1: sends query "select * from table1"
async2: sends query "insert into table2 ..."
async1: expects to fetch rows of result set, but receives only rows-affected and last insertid
```

It gets worse from there, for example, a query cannot execute while there's an existing query with a result set that hasn't closed its result set. Or even worse, you could prepare two queries that have parameters, then subsequently send parameters for the *wrong* query.

You can use the same database connection for many queries, but DO NOT share the same connection among concurrently executing async threads. To be safe, each async routine should open its own connection. Then the thread that opened a given connection can use that connection for multiple queries.

Think of it like a call center, where dozens of people each have their own phone line. They certainly should not try to share a single phone line and carry on multiple conversations! The only way that could work is if every word uttered on the phone carried some identifying information for which conversation it belonged to. "Hi this is Mr. Smith calling about case #1234, and the answer to the question you just asking me is..."

But MySQL's protocol doesn't do that. It assumes that each message is a continuation of the previous one, and both client and server remember what that is.